# Using And,Or in a sql for multiple results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, where-clause

I have a textbox and 3 dropdown boxes with an item that could be selected in each of the dropdowns. There are two filtering scenarios I want to be able to achieve.

1. Getting a filtering result after typing a value in the textbox and select values in the next two textboxes leaving out the last one.
2. Getting a filtering after typing a value in the textbox and select values in the other three dropdown boxes to filter out the result. My code below can only produce each of the results one at a time If I change the "and" to "or" and the "or"s to "and"s. Can anyone help with  modification or new query to be able to achieve the two scenarios?

---

```
CREATE PROC Spsearchproduct @searchWord1OnMasterPage NVARCHAR (50),
                            @searchWord2OnMasterPage NVARCHAR (50),
                            @searchWord3OnMasterPage NVARCHAR (50),
                            @searchWord4OnMasterPage NVARCHAR (50)
AS
  BEGIN
      SELECT product.NAME,
             price,
             seller,
             productstreetno.strno,
             productstreet.streetname
      FROM   product
             INNER JOIN productstreetno
                     ON product.streetnoid = productstreetno.idstreetno
             INNER JOIN productstreet
                     ON product.streetid = productstreet.idstreet
             INNER JOIN productstate
                     ON stateid = productstate.idstate
             INNER JOIN productcity
                     ON cityid = productcity.idcity
      WHERE  product.NAME LIKE '%' + @searchWord1OnMasterPage + '%'
             AND productstate.statename LIKE '%' + @searchWord2OnMasterPage + '%'
             AND ( ( productcity.cityname LIKE '%' + @searchWord3OnMasterPage + '%' )
                    OR ( productstreet.streetname LIKE '%' + @searchWord4OnMasterPage + '%' )
                    OR ( productstreet.streetname IS NULL ) )
             AND ( ( productcity.cityname LIKE '%' + @searchWord3OnMasterPage + '%' )
                    OR ( productstreet.streetname LIKE '%' + @searchWord4OnMasterPage + '%' )
                    OR ( productstreet.streetname IS NULL ) )
  END
```

Comment: Which Parameter represent value of TextBox and dropdown?

Comment: Thank you JaydipJ. They are all string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Product.Name Like '%' + @searchWord1OnMasterPage + '%' and
    ProductState.StateName Like '%' + @searchWord2OnMasterPage + '%' and
    (ProductCity.CityName Like '%' + @searchWord3OnMasterPage + '%' )and
    ((ProductStreet.StreetName Like '%' + @searchWord4OnMasterPage + '%') or
    (@searchWord4OnMasterPage = 'Select Street'))
```

Comment: The 'select Street' is the default value in the dropdown